References and useful results on continuous one-parameter intersection of algebraic surfaces
Consider a one-parameter family of polynomials $\{P_t\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]\}_{t\in I}$ and a continuous curve $\gamma:J\to \mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose that
$$P_t(\gamma(s)) =0, \quad \forall (t,s)\in I\times J.$$
So basically we're saying that the trace of the curve $\gamma$ lies on every (and therefore, in the intersection) algebraic curve defined by $P_t(X,Y)=0$. Then, algebraic geometry tells us that we have two possibilities:


The curve $\gamma$ is constant;
Otherwise, for any pair $t_1,t_2\in I$ the algebraic curves associated to $P_{t_1}$ and $P_{t_2}$ have infinite intersection and, therefore, $P_{t_1}$ and $P_{t_2}$ must have a nonconstant common factor. Additionally, if we have that some $P_{t_0}$ is irreducible, then $P_{t_0}$ is a common factor for the whole family.


I'm interested in the following similar problem:

Let $\{P_t\}_{t\in I}$ denote a one-parameter family of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y,Z]$ and $\gamma:J\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a space curve such that $P_t(\gamma(s))=0$, for every $(t,s)\in I\times J$. Can we say anything about $P_t$ if $\gamma$ is nonconstant?

I honestly don't know if we can expect much and, as I see, this seems to be a very difficult question to answer. Even if $\gamma$ is nonconstant, the surfaces can just be transversal. Also, they can also intersect on a open set, with enough space to contain the curve. On the other side, this is a whole one-parameter family of surfaces, all containing the same curve, which suggests that they should lose some of their deformation freedom ... However, I don't know much about algebraic surfaces intersection theory. Maybe someone can recommend references and useful results. I would really appreciate that!
PS: I don't know if it helps, but of course we're supposing the family is continuous and has finite maximum degree, i.e. $P_t$ can be described as
$$P_t(X,Y,Z)=\sum_{i,j,k=0}^n a_{i,j,k}(t)X^iY^j Z^k,$$
for a fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and continuous functions $a_{i,j,k}:I\to \mathbb{R}$.

It doesn't matter too much whether you take $\gamma$ to be a curve or something more arbitrary, due to the existence of space-filling curves and so forth. The fact that the $P_t$ are a parametric family of polynomials also does not really matter. The core of your question is the following:

What can we say about a polynomial $P \in \mathbb{R}[X, Y, Z]$ given that it vanishes on a subset $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$?

The answer is that we can associate to every subset $V$ the collection of polynomials that vanish on it; this is an ideal $I_V$ in $\mathbb{R}[X, Y, Z]$, and by Hilbert's basis theorem it is finitely generated. This means that there is a finite set of polynomials $P_1, \dots P_n$ vanishing on $V$, depending only on $V$, such that every polynomial $P$ vanishing on $V$ has the form
$$P = \sum Q_i P_i$$
where $Q_i \in \mathbb{R}[X, Y, Z]$ are arbitrary. The $P_i$ have a common zero locus $\overline{V} = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^3 : P_i(v) = 0 \}$ which by definition contains $V$ but will frequently be larger; it is called the Zariski closure of $V$, and the answer to the problem does not change if we replace $V$ with its Zariski closure.
Here are some examples coming from curves, although without proofs that the ideals actually are generated by what I'm claiming they are.

If we take $\gamma(s) = (s, 0, 0)$, then its image $V$ is Zariski closed. The ideal $I_V$ is generated by $Y$ and $Z$, which means that the polynomials vanishing on $V$ are exactly the polynomials of the form $Q_1 Y + Q_2 Z$. This should hopefully be pretty intuitive.
If we take $\gamma(s) = (\cos s, \sin s, 0)$, then its image $V$ is Zariski closed. The ideal $I_V$ is generated by $X^2 + Y^2 - 1$ and $Z$, which means that the polynomials vanishing on $V$ have the form $Q_1 (X^2 + Y^2 - 1) + Q_2 Z$.
If we take $\gamma(s) = (s, e^s, 0)$, then its image $V$ is not Zariski closed. Its Zariski closure is the plane $(s, t, 0)$, and the ideal $I_V$ is generated by a single polynomial $Z$, so the polynomials vanishing on $V$ have the form $Q Z$.
If we take $\gamma(s) = (s, s^2, s^3)$ (the twisted cubic), then its image $V$ is Zariski closed. The ideal $I_V$ is generated by the polynomials $X^2 - Y, XY - Z, XZ - Y^2$ (it's known that $3$ polynomials are necessary here even though $V$ has codimension $2$; this means that $V$ is not a scheme-theoretic complete intersection), which means that the polynomials vanishing on $V$ have the form $Q_1 (X^2 - Y) + Q_2 (XY - Z) + Q_3 (XZ - Y^2)$.

If $\gamma(s)$ is a polynomial then I believe explicit algorithms are known for computing a set of generators for the corresponding ideal $I_V$ but I'm not familiar with them; this should be somewhere in the literature on Gröbner bases and/or Chevalley's theorem.

Your answer gives really good insight on it. Thanks! I'll consider it enough for the bounty already. However, it helps me now to realize my question should be: take the parametric family of polynomials: it is basically a continuous curve into an ideal, $I_V$, and it is degree bounded. As you said, $I_V$ is finitely generated. Do you think we can say anything of such a curve?

Maybe we need to talk about a topology on $I_V$.

@Derso: so the natural guess is that if $P_t$ is a continuous family of polynomials vanishing on $V$ then it can be written $P_t = \sum Q_t P_i$ where $Q_t$ are continuous families of polynomials. I don't know if this is true; the issue is that the $Q_t$ are not unique in general. This would probably be worth asking as a separate question.
